# CAML Query "Neq" not working with choice field

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, jsom

I an writing one CALM query as below. But seems like `Neq` is not working for choice field. I am getting wrong results.

Does anyone know the work around.

```
<View><Query><Where>
    <And>
        <Or>
            <Or>
                <Eq><FieldRef Name='FirstReminder' /> <Value IncludeTimeValue='False' Type='DateTime'><Today OffsetDays='-3'/></Value></Eq>
                <Eq><FieldRef Name='SecondReminder' /> <Value IncludeTimeValue='False' Type='DateTime'><Today OffsetDays='-6'/></Value></Eq>
            </Or>
            <Eq><FieldRef Name='ThirdReminder' /> <Value IncludeTimeValue='False' Type='DateTime'><Today OffsetDays='-9'/></Value></Eq>
        </Or>
        <Or>
            <Neq><FieldRef Name='Document_x0020_Status' /><Value Type='Choice'>Obsolete</Value></Neq>
            <Neq><FieldRef Name='Document_x0020_Validity' /><Value Type='Choice'>Obsolete</Value></Neq>
        </Or>
    </And>
</Where></Query></View>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I tested with two choice fields with same field name without other condition and it works as expected:

[image]

Suggest to test with Caml Designer to build the correct result:

[Caml Designer Download](https://www.biwug.be/resources)